# How to change specific XML attribute of custom UI element programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am using a custom UI component in my project which has it's own few attributes. I want to change a specific one using a function when it is clicked. I don't know how to access it though, I am fairly new in this department.

```
<com.chinodev.androidneomorphframelayout.NeomorphFrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/btnsystem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:neomorph_background_color="@color/appBackground"
                    app:neomorph_corner_radius="10dp"
                    app:neomorph_elevation="4dp"
                    app:neomorph_highlight_color="#ffffff"
                    app:neomorph_shadow_color="#CDCDCD"
                    app:neomorph_view_type="rectangular">
```

here say I want to change the `app:neomorph_elevation` using onclick function how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In `NeomorphFrameLayout` you can add a public function changeElevation ex

```
 fun changeElevation(elevation :Float){
      neomorph_elevation = elevation
    }
```

and can use in onClickListener like

```
btnsystem.changeElevation(5f)
```

Answer (score 0):

As they specified in library that,

Attributes: neomorph_clickable option set it to true and onClick trigger a function from xml or from setOnClickListener whichever you prefer...

https://github.com/4inodev/Neomorphic-FrameLayout-Android

Answer (score 0):

## android-repository-history

History of Android repository XML

### repository2-$N.xml and addons_list-3.xml

Used by `sdkmanager` command.

### repository-$N.xml and addons_list-2.xml

Used by `android` command, which is deprecated and unavailable in the latest Android SDK Tools (since r25.3.0)